# Remove some variables from Boolean expression in SymPy

Tags: python, boolean, sympy, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a Boolean expression in SymPy. If I know the values of some of symbols, how can I find the relation between the rest of the symbols?
For example:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import Symbol
from sympy.logic.boolalg import Equivalent
from sympy import simplify_logic
a=Symbol("a")
b=Symbol("b")
c=Symbol("c")
d=Symbol("d")
e=Symbol("e")

expr=a&b>>c|a&d|~a&Equivalent(c,(d|a&e))
print("if a=True and d=False, then relation between a,c and e must be")#c|~b
```

alternatively: I have a Boolean function `f(a,b,c,k,l,j)`. How to solve for `k`,`l` and `j` if `a`,`b` and `c` are known? I know that I have to form a new expression that is true on any values of `a`, `b` and `c`, but how to do it?

```
simplify_logic((eeldus&expr))                    #leaves a and d in.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, [`subs`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) would work:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> a, b, c, d, e = symbols('a b c d e')
>>> expr = a & b >> c | a & d | ~a & Equivalent(c,(d | a & e))
>>> expr.subs([(a,true),(d,false)])
Implies(b, c)
```